# Java regex (Failed some usecase)

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I'm having some string issues and, after researching online, I think the lookahead is what i need. However, I'm facing the issue of not being able to get my expected result in some cases.

Basically, I'm given a string that is delimited by "/" and a "-", and I have to find all the parents of the string. There will only be three level.

> A/LEVEL ONE/LEVEL TWO-LEVEL THREE

1. Each Level can contains (A, B or C) at the end of each level, but
   will still be counted as the same level despite the "/".
2. Each Level can contain CD(NNN), it will not have any children, but its
   possible that (AB/C) is appended behind it, e.g. A/100 CD(100)
   (AB/C), this will still be consider as Level One.

```java
public void findRoot(String value){
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("?=/[^/]* & [AB/C])|(?=-)");
    String results = pattern.split(value)
    for (String result : results){
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

My Expected Result...

```
A/100/200 => A/100
A/100 (AB/C)/200 => A/100 (AB/C)
A/100 APPLE/200 => A/100 APPLE
A/100 APPLE (AB/C)/200 => A/100 APPLE (AB/C)
A/100 (AB/C)/200 ORANGE=> A/100 (AB/C)
A/100 APPLE/200 ORANGE => A/100 APPLE
A/100 APPLE (AB/C)/200 ORANGE => A/100 APPLE (AB/C)
A/100 APPLE (AB/C)/200 ORANGE (AB/C)=> A/100 APPLE (AB/C)
A/100 APPLE (AB/C)/200 ORANGE CD(100)=> A/100 APPLE (AB/C)/200 ORANGE
A/100 APPLE (AB/C)/200 ORANGE CD(100) (AB/C)=> A/100 APPLE (AB/C)/200 ORANGE
```

It's getting messy here...

```
A/100/200-300 => A/100/200
A/100/200 APPLE-300 => A/100/200 APPLE
A/100/200 APPLE-300 CD(200)=> A/100/200 APPLE-300
A/100/200 APPLE-300 CD(200) (AB/C)=> A/100/200 APPLE-300
```

Some example of bad results...

```
A/100 APPLE/200 ORANGE => A/100 APPLE/200 ORANGE
A/100/200 APPLE-300 CD(200) (AB/C) => A/100/200 APPLE, -300 CD(200) (AB/C)
```

If i do additional manipulation to  A/100/200 APPLE, -300 CD(200) (AB/C), I can still get the expected result. How can I make the code more lean and clean and work as required?

Comment: And the bad result is...?

Comment: Try debugging your regex on [regex101](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: You have not yet done a good job of explaining what you are trying to do.